# How can I find out which email address of mine an email I was bcc'd on was sent to?

Tags: gmail

I've received an email in my inbox (Gmail). I was bcc'd on this email. This inbox actually receives emails from a large number of email addresses, which are then forwarded to my Gmail address. Is there any way to establish which address the email was originally sent to?

I can see the original domain the email was sent to in the message header, but I actually have many addresses from this domain forwarded to my Gmail inbox.

Answer (score 2):

Open up the "more" menu for the message. (It's the down arrow next to "Reply".)

Choose "show original."

Scroll down and look for `Delivered-To:` headers. (There are probably more than one, depending on how many forwards there are.)

That'll tell you to what address the message was originally sent to, independent of what may be in the `To:` or `Cc:` fields.

This is also the header searched by the `deliveredto:` search operator.

Comment: I've done this. There is only one field which contains the text "deliver", and this shows the final gmail address. So it doesn't do the job.

Comment: Then I'm afraid there isn't any other way to do this, short of changing how you're forwarding the messages.